# Pandas GroupBy: apply a function with two arguments

Tags: python, pandas

Usually when using the `.apply()` method, one passes a function that takes exactly one argument.

```
def somefunction(group):
    group['ColumnC'] == group['ColumnC']**2
    return group

df.groupby(['ColumnA', 'ColumnB']).apply(somefunction)
```

Here `somefunction` is applied for each `group`, which is then returned. Basically I'm using this [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22678651/4791226).

I want to have the ability to *not specify* the column name `ColumnC` beforehand. Passing it along as an argument of `somefunction` would make the code more flexible.

```
def somefunction(group, column_name):
    group[column_name] == group[column_name]**2
    return group

df.groupby(['ColumnA', 'ColumnB']).apply(somefunction)
```

Is there any way to make this work? I can't pass `group` to `somefunction`, because that is magically done by `.apply()` in the background.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you can pass key word arguments through `apply`

```
df.groupby(['ColumnA', 'ColumnB']).apply(somefunction, column_name='col')
```

---

[***MCVE***](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=list(range(2)) * 5, B=range(10)[::-1]))

def f(df, arg1):
    return df * arg1

df.groupby('A').apply(f, arg1=3)

   A   B
0  0  27
1  3  24
2  0  21
3  3  18
4  0  15
5  3  12
6  0   9
7  3   6
8  0   3
9  3   0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make an anonymous function

`df.groupby(['ColumnA', 'ColumnB']).apply(lambda x: somefunction(x, 'col'))`